# How to change the name of the ToC when I use poemscol

Tags: table-of-contents, languages, poemscol

I am writing a poetry book using the poemscol package. It has its own commands for creating a ToC. However, my poetry book isn't in English, so I want the title of my ToC not be "Contents" in english, but "Contents" in my own language

```
\putpoemcontents
\makepoemcontents
```

After compiling twice, this gives you the ToC

Comment: Try this: `\pmclcontentsname={CONTENTS in my own language}`

Comment: It worked, thank you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times,fancyhdr,poemscol}
\pmclcontentsname={CONTENTS in my own language}
\begin{document}
\putpoemcontents
\makepoemcontents
\end{document}
```